# Unable to insert data in Hive Table with Load data

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to insert data into Hive Server with command "load data local inpath 'C:\User\HiveData_Employ.csv' into table table1swa;" command. The csv is in my local machine. And the data in the CSV is {21,Name1}. But i am getting an error like below:

FAILED: IllegalArgumentException java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: C:%5CSwarup%5CHiveData_Employ.csv (state=42000,code=40000)

What am i doing wrong here as i think i should mention local as i am loading data from my local machine and not from HDFS path.Also please confirm the input data is correct..

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing Backslash 
as below
C:/User/HiveData_Employ.csv' into table table1swa

Also the input data looks good